# subtract column of scipy.sparse matrix from a vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to find a way to subtract a column of a `scipy.sparse` matrix from a `numpy` vector but I can't seem to find a way to do it without changing the shape of the vector. This is what I have so far:

```
>>> import scipy.sparse
>>> import numpy
>>> A = scipy.sparse.eye(10)
>>> A = A.tolil()
>>> x = numpy.ones(10)
>>> x
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> x.shape
(10,)
>>> x -= A[:,5].T
>>> x
matrix([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> x.shape
(1, 10)
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this? I guess I could use `numpy.reshape` but maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it is twice as fast if you do:

```
x -= A[:,5].toarray().flatten()
```

and it avoids the shape problem... using this suggestion and `csr_matrix` for matrix `A` gives a speed up of 10 times...

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse

x = np.ones(10)
A = A = scipy.sparse.eye(10).tolil()
%timeit np.asarray(x-A[:,5].T).flatten()
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.3 ms per loop
%timeit x-A[:,5].toarray().flatten()
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 494 µs per loop

A = A.tocsc()
%timeit np.asarray(x-A[:,5].T).flatten()
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 410 µs per loop
%timeit x-A[:,5].toarray().flatten()
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 334 µs per loop

A = A.tocsr()
%timeit np.asarray(x-A[:,5].T).flatten()
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 264 µs per loop
%timeit x-A[:,5].toarray().flatten()
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 185 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It works just fine. Now about your suggestion of using a `csr_matrix` instead, I didn't use this format because I don't think you can construct the matrix easily by adding individual elements. Also, how did you time it? Can you provide the code so that your answer is complete?

Comment: @aaragon I timed it using IPython... it is very straightforward using the magic directive `timeit`... I will update the answer...

Comment: Usually you use the sparse format that suits the construction process, and then convert it to the format that suits usage (here, calculation).  Internally sparse does a lot of that conversion.

Comment: You can replace `.toarray()` with `.A`, which makes it less cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute fastest, especially if your matrix is very sparse, is almost certainly going to be to use a CSC format and do the following:

```
>>> A = A.tocsc()
>>> A.sum_duplicates() # just in case...
>>> col = 5
>>> sl = slice(A.indptr[col], A.indptr[col+1])
>>> data = A.data[sl]
>>> indices = A.indices[sl]
>>> out = x.copy()
>>> out[indices] -= data
>>> out
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

There is that old adage that "readability counts", which this doesn't do too well with, though...